# create a third list by combining values in two lists

Tags: python, list

I have to two arrays (in my code below): "donlist" is a list of random donation amounts between $1 and $100, and "charlist" is a list of random charity numbers between 1 and 15. I need to create a third array using the total donations for each charity. So if charity #3 appears 8 times in "charlist", I have to get the sum of the corresponding floats from "donlist". I have absolutely no idea how to do this and have been trying to figure it out for the past 2-3 hours now. Does anyone know how to do it? Thank you.

```
import random
from array import *

counter = 0
donlist = []
charlist = []

while counter != 100:
    d = random.uniform(1.00,100.00)
    c = random.randint(1,15)
    counter +=1
    donlist.append(d)
    donlist = [round(elem,2) for elem in donlist]
    charlist.append(c)
    if counter == 100:
        break
```

Sample output:

```
Charity    Total Donations
1          802.65
2          1212.25
3          108.25
4          9324.12
5          534.98
6          6235.12
7          223.18
8          11.12
9          3345.68
10         856.68
11         7123.05
12         6125.86
13         1200.25
14         468.32
15         685.26
```

Comment: Can you give a simple example of input and expected output to make things crystal clear?

Comment: Oh sure I'll add that now

Comment: In Python, array and list are two different things.

Comment: in your example charities appear only once. Also you don't provide expected output.

Comment: `random.uniform(1.00, 100.00)` won't result in integer numbers you have now. And it's *very* unlikely they would add up to exactly 100: that would mean each donation is exactly $1, since you loop 100 times in your code.

Comment: @Evert sorry I totally confused that with the next part of my assignment, which is to create a fourth array (I'm just doing lists lol) that outputs the number of donations for each charity. I was thinking that that sum must equal 100. Thanks! (I've been staring at this problem for too long lol)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `dict`, with the charity number as the key. You simply add the donation to the corresponding `dict` value. If the `dict` element doesn't exist yet, set it to zero as its initial value.
I'm using `defaultdict`: the `lambda: 0` argument will guarantee a zero value if the key doesn't exist yet, otherwise you can just add to it.

Updating your script (with a few minor other alterations):

```
import random
from collections import defaultdict

donlist = []
charlist = []
totals = defaultdict(float)

counter = 0
while counter != 100:
    counter += 1
    d = random.uniform(1.00,100.00)  
    c = random.randint(1,15)  
    donlist.append(d)      
    donlist = [round(elem,2) for elem in donlist]
    charlist.append(c)      
    totals[c] += d
```

nb: I removed the `array` import, since you're only using `list`s in the code.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how I can get "totals" to give two decimal place results? Or rather, how I can format "d"? I originally formatted "donlist" instead because I wasn't able to format "d" itself. I just tried changing the code to "d = round(random.uniform(1.00,100.00),2)" but some values in totals still have very long decimals.

Comment: Use string formatting. E.g., use something like `"{:.2f}".format(123.456789)` and you'll end up with a string `"123.46"`.

Comment: I used your defaultdict concept to create a fourth array, "totalnum" that calculates how many donations were given per charity. I now have to calculate the average donation per charity, but I can't divide the two lists because they both have the charity numbers in there as well. Do you know how I can do this? Thank you so much!

Comment: That's a different question.

Comment: Okay I'll ask in a new question! Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

This seems a good example to use the [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function. It gets two lists as argument (in your case the `donlist` and `charlist`) and creates an iterator of these, so you can iterate one time adding the values from `donlist` in the right charity position. `zip` example:

```py
for a, b in zip(range(1, 5), range(5, 10)):
    print(a, b)
```

will output

```
1 5
2 6
3 7
4 8
```

I strongly recommend generating the data lists before creating the third, so you can do

```py
donlist = [ random.uniform(1.0, 100.0) for _ in range(0, 100) ]
charlist = [ random.randint(1, 15) for _ in range(0, 100) ]
```

This is a simple syntax to create a list from an iterator. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

This way, you can guarantee that it works for cases when these lists are not generated during the calculation, for an example, where the user input the values.

After the lists generation / input you can just:

```py
# this is the same as a list comprehension but for a dict
# https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries
result = { char : 0 for char in range(1, 16) }
for don, char in zip(donlist, charlist):
    result[char] += don
```

In the end each charity `N` has it's donation value in `result[N]`.

Comment: Can somebody explain me why this got downvoted? Thanks

Comment: Downvotes happen randomly. But perhaps someone felt there's too much magic without an explanation: `zip` by itself doesn't do the work.

Comment: I understand, I'm changing this reply to add more information. Thanks!

Comment: If that can comfort you, I recently got -5 for a similar valid but not explained answer... Some people are angry.

Comment: Lol I've gotten my account banned for two weeks before for getting -12 on a question I just did not understand. I never try to get people to do my homework for me.. I just really don't understand a lot of things (it's my first Python class).

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> l1 = [1,1,3,4] # charity list
>>> l2 = [5,6,7,8] # donation list
>>> zip(l1,l2)
[(1, 5), (1, 6), (3, 7), (4, 8)]

>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> for k,v in zip(l1,l2):
...    d[k] += v
...
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {1: 11, 3: 7, 4: 8})
```

You can now index `d` by charity number and get the value of donation.